# Shortcode for an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
$array = array('Autobus', 'Ecole', 'Hopital' ...);
```

And this is how I echo images that are in that array

```
foreach ($array as $prox){
    if ($prox == 'Autobus'){
        echo '<img src="./imgs/icones/autobus.png" width="35" height="35" alt="'.$prox.'" title="'.$prox.'"/>';
    }
    if ($prox == 'Ecole'){
        echo '<img src="./imgs/icones/ecole.png" width="35" height="35" alt="'.$prox.'" title="'.$prox.'"/>';
    }
    if ($prox == 'Hopital'){
        echo '<img src="./imgs/icones/hopital.png" width="35" height="35" alt="'.$prox.'" title="'.$prox.'"/>';
    }
...
```

Is there any way shorter than that code to do the same thing ?

Thanks

Comment: Question title is a bit of a misnomer, made me think of the [PHP 5.4 short syntax for arrays.](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $prox){
    echo '<img src="./imgs/icones/' . strtolower($prox) . '.png" width="35" height="35" alt="'.$prox.'" title="'.$prox.'"/>';
}
```

Comment: I have some images name that are not == as the item in the array but when I think about it, why I don't rename those :D. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('Autobus', 'Ecole', 'Hopital');
foreach($array as $prox) {
   echo '<img src="./imgs/icones/'.strtolower($prox).'.png" width="35" height="35" alt="'.$prox.'" title="'.$prox.'"/>';
}
```

Comment: Ha! Let's play who can type the fastest! I wasn't even on the page a minute, some of those answers should have been up when I came in. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $prox){
$img = strtolower ($prox);
echo '<img src="./imgs/icones/'.$img.'autobus.png" width="35" height="35" alt="'.$prox.'" title="'.$prox.'"/>';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $prox){
    sprintf('<img src="./imgs/icones/%s.png" width="35" height="35" alt="%s" title="%s"/>'
            , strtolower($prox)
            , $prox
            , $prox);
}
```

This only works if the image name is the same (but lowercase) as `$prox`

Comment: Personal opinion: `sprintf()` is overkill for for any kind of simple variable insertion, and again in my opinion ruins the readability of code (I used to use it religiously, now I don't).

Comment: Personal opinion: `sprintf()` is fine for for this kind of simple variable insertion, and again in my opinion can help the readability of code (I sometimes use it, now and then).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

The above posters did it how I was originally going to do it, but what if you have a word like "Chemin de fer"?

At least I think that's French...

```
$aArray = array
(
    "autobus" => "Autobus",
    "ecole" => "Ecole",
    "hopital" => "Hopital",
);

foreach($aArray as $sImageName => $sTitle)
{
    echo '<img src="/imgs/icones/'.$sImageName.'.png" width="35" height="35" title="'.$sTitle.'" />';
}
```

Tadaa?